# Is Binary Table structure changed in Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We did a upgrade from Tridion 5.3 to Tridion 2011 SP1. While checking the Broker database tables we have found that structure and name of BINARIES table is changed. 
In Tridion 5.3 we had table called BINARIES with columns PATH and URL, But when we check the same in Tridion 2011 SP1 we cannot find the BINARIES table, rather we have table BINARY which don't have column PATH and URL. In which table we can find PATH and URL columns. Which table is updated when we publish Binary content from Tridion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PATH and URL columns are now in the **BINARYVARIANTS** table.

But be careful of introducing such dependencies on the database structure. SDL publishes an API for accessing the Content Delivery database and most use-cases can be met by using this API.

One of the main advantages of sticking to this public API is that your code will largely be insulated from upgrade problems as the one you are experiencing here. SDL spends considerable effort to keep the API kept backwards compatibly between product releases, while the database structure is changed "at will".